# Android BLE characteristic gives back wrong string

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android app which use ble to communicate with a device.
The problem i'm facing with is the characteristic.getStringValue(0) gives back a wrong string:

what i meant:

on htc,(some galaxy s5, htc android 5.0.2, galaxy s5 android 5.0), i got back (as firmware version) 111
any other device i've got back the right 1.1.1 firmware version as string.

Can you help me how can i solve this problem?

Thank you!

some code:

```
else if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(WiweBLEUuids.WW_BLE_CHARACTERISTIC_FIRMWARE_REVISION_UUID)) {
firmwareVersion = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
checkConnectionStatusAndSendBroadcastIfConnected();
}
```

**i have some update:**

when it reads 1.1.1 it reads the serial number uuid, not the firmvare version uuid.

Comment: How are you getting your characteristic? The problem is most likely in the way you find the characteristic

Comment: i figuired it out when the bluetooth stack is congusted hta's when i get the problem